# Please help figure out names of Chinese artists by their seals!

Tags: characters, seal

helping a friend figure out who painted these works and wondering if anyone can decipher the characters in the seals.  Thanks! [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wow... this is hard. Let me have a guess:

馬不白/馬不百/馬本白？
宋民/宗民/金民？
慧玉昊？

The last one seems to be easy:

林生书画

Those on the seals/stamps are normally in font of some variant of JinZhaun(金篆) which is not kind of writing in our daily life anymore, not to say the variantation that twist for personalize.